# Unity scripting Ambient light turns off but I can't turn it back on with the same button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried a few ways of doing it. I've asked a few friends but, nothing seems to work so far. I have changed the script several times so I don't have the other ways that I have tried anymore. However, this is the one that gave me the least errors. Others I had to continuously change it to a recommended way by Unity but ended at a dead end and nothing worked.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightActivator : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);

        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to turn on and off the ambient/directional light with just 1 button. Is that not possible?

Comment: While you deactivate the item even if this was on another item and gameobject was your ambient light your logic is currently flawed as you have said if apace is pressed turn it off. You mean if space is pressed and light ison. And the else becomes if space is pressed and light is off

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#` ... also did you read the tag description of [`script`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/script/info) ...? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two little flaws here

1. after you do

   ```
   gameObject.SetActive(false);
   ```

   this very same object is now inactive -> this component as well -> `Update` is no longer being called at all ;)
2. You always will ever only treat the first case .. the second one is never called at all since the condition will always match already with the first block!

---

Instead separate the logic from the target object and do e.g.

```
// This class should go to a different object that is always active in your scene
public class LightActivator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here you reference the object you want to (de)activate via drag&drop in the Inspector
    public GameObject theLight;

    void Update()
    {
        // You only need one condition check
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // INVERT the active state of the light object whatever it currently is
            theLight.SetActive(!theLight.activeSelf); 
        }   
    }
}
```

In order to keep things together you could e.g. simply make the according light object a child of the `LightActivator` object ;)

Comment: That's actually a lot simpler than what I tried... Been at it for like 30 mins. xd
Thank you!